# build and deploy iOS app to local device using CLI

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, capacitor

In switching from Cordova to Capacitor we seem to have lost the ability to deploy our app to physical devices using the command line. This is helpful so that our automated build process can push it out to a set of devices we have connected to the server. All the docs for deploying with Capacitor say to open Xcode and select a device for deployment. I'm trying with instruments to get the device ID and then xcodebuild to install it

```
instruments -s devices | grep -v Simulator | grep -e iPhone -e iPad 
xcodebuild install -workspace ios/App/App.xcworkspace -scheme App -destination 'platform=iOS,id=76a....781'
```

And even though this ends with ** install succeeded ** the app has not been installed on the device

Answer (score 1):

You can consider bumping your Capacitor version to v3.0.0 rc3.. The team is building upon a new command to run the app on device without opening the native ide.

`npx cap run ios`

[Source](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/ios#running-on-the-command-line) [Discussion Capacitor v3](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3133)

Alternative - Use [Ionic Appflow](https://ionic.io/appflow) for deployments.

For Appflow builds on the cloud.. You can do two things there..

- Live Deploy - if you have just made any changes to the code, the js, HTML, css side, then use LiveDeploy, this will be much faster for deploying to all the app users.
- Native Builds - incase you have added any new plugin or made native configuration changes, then make a native build that can deploy it to test flight and then your tester's can download the updated version from there..

You can also set auto triggers for these workflows as well when you commit your code to the repository.

Comment: That looks useful thanks. Doesn't AppFlow do it all on their servers? So it can't get it on to devices we have here in the office

Comment: yes, it builds on their cloud.. but check my updated answer for some more info.

Answer (score 1):

If waiting for Capacitor 3 is not an option these three lines work

`xcodebuild -workspace ios/App/App.xcworkspace/ -scheme App -archivePath ./ios/App.xcarchive archive`

`xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ./ios/App.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist ./ios/App/export-development.plist -exportPath ./iOS`

`ios-deploy --debug --bundle ios/App.ipa`